# Django - RelatedObjectDoesNotExist error after post_save creation signal

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have general user profile model which has several roles - Client, Translator and Editor. I'm using a one-to-one relation with the extended user model I've created in accounts app and I'm using Django post_save signal to automatically create a profile instance related to the user which works just fine.
Now here is the problem: I need to have role-specific profile model like client profile, translator profile, etc. and again I'm trying to use Django post_save signal to create a {role} profile object related to the main UserProfile model and I'm getting the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 614, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 233, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 89, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\admin.py", line 99, in add_view
    return self._add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\admin.py", line 126, in _add_view
    return super().add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1653, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1534, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1580, in _changeform_view
    self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1093, in save_model
    obj.save()
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 67, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 753, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 801, in save_base
    post_save.send(
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 177, in send
    return [
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 178, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "D:\Django\tct\src\profiles\models.py", line 73, in create_user_profile
    UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 447, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 753, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 801, in save_base
    post_save.send(
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 177, in send
    return [
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 178, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "D:\Django\tct\src\clients\models.py", line 32, in save_client_profile
    instance.clientprofile.save()
  File "D:\Django\tct\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 421, in __get__
    raise self.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist(

Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /admin/accounts/user/add/
Exception Value: UserProfile has no clientprofile.
```

#### User Model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        _("User ID"), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False
    )
```

#### General Profile Model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # General Info
    CLIENT = 1
    TRANSLATOR = 2
    EDITOR = 3
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (CLIENT, _("Client")),
        (TRANSLATOR, _("Translator")),
        (EDITOR, _("Editor")),
    )
    MALE = 1
    FEMALE = 2
    GENDER_CHOICES = ((MALE, _("Male")), (FEMALE, _("Female")))
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, verbose_name=_("User"), on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True
    )
    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        _("Role"), choices=ROLE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True
    )
    bio = models.TextField(_("Bio"), null=True, blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(
        _("Avatar"), upload_to="profiles/profile/avatar/", blank=True
    )
    gender = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        _("Gender"), choices=GENDER_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True
    )

    # Contact Info
    phone = models.CharField(_("Phone"), max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    cell = models.CharField(_("Cell"), max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    id_number = models.CharField(_("ID Number"), max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(_("Address"), null=True, blank=True)
    postal_code = models.CharField(
        _("Postal Code"), max_length=20, null=True, blank=True
    )
    website_url = models.URLField(
        _("Website URL"), max_length=200, null=True, blank=True
    )
    instagram_username = models.CharField(
        _("Instagram Username"), max_length=200, null=True, blank=True
    )
    telegram_username = models.CharField(
        _("Telegram Username"), max_length=200, null=True, blank=True
    )
    twitter_username = models.CharField(
        _("Twitter Username"), max_length=200, null=True, blank=True
    )

    # Model Extra
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("User Profile")
        verbose_name_plural = _("User Profile")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("profiles:user_profile_detail", args=[str(self.user.id)])


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.userprofile.save()
```

#### Client Profile Model

```
class ClientProfile(models.Model):
    profile = models.OneToOneField(
        UserProfile, verbose_name=_("User"), on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True
    )
    credit = models.IntegerField(_("Credit"), default=0, blank=True)
    debt = models.IntegerField(_("Debt"), default=0, blank=True)
    referral_code = ULIDField(default=default)
    referrals = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, verbose_name=_("Referrals"), related_name="client_profile"
    )
    income = models.IntegerField(_("Income"), default=0, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=UserProfile)
def create_client_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.role == 1:
            ClientProfile.objects.create(profile=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=UserProfile)
def save_client_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.clientprofile.save()
```

#### Custom sign up form with the role field

```
class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
    role = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(), choices=UserProfile.ROLE_CHOICES, required=False, label=_("Role")
    )

    def save(self, request):

        # Ensure you call the parent class's save.
        # .save() returns a User object.
        user = super(CustomSignupForm, self).save(request)
        user.userprofile.role = self.cleaned_data.get("role")
        user.save()
        # You must return the original result.
        return user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's running the `save_client_profile` and complaining that the `UserProfile` has no `client_profile` attached. The `create_client_profile`'s `role == 1` condition isn't met because the UserProfile's role is not set upon creation.

The `save()` method of `SignUpForm` currently sets the role in memory but doesn't commit it to the database, because `user.save()` only saves the User model, not its related UserProfile. You'll need to do `user.userprofile.save()` after `user.userprofile.role = self.cleaned_data.get("role")` for the role to persist.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm populating the role field using user sign up form, which currently inherits from django-allauth SignupForm class. It works just fine I think and I have the role choice available in signup view. Edited question and added the form.

Comment: Looks like you're not saving the UserProfile in the save() method, only the user: `user.userprofile.save()` after you set the role should do it.

Comment: omg! you're right. I just need to save the userprofile after saving user in sign up form's save function. Edit the answer so I can mark it as accepted. thanks